# WFFM range input control

Tags: wffm

WFFM matter doesn't seem to have an input range built-in, how do I go about creating a custom field input range for WFFM?

Comment: have a look here : https://sitecorejunkie.com/2014/04/24/add-the-html5-range-input-control-into-web-forms-for-marketers-in-sitecore/